# Winforms control for tile based map editor

Tags: c++, winforms, dictionary, controls

I've recently made a game engine that reads an xml based level format from a tutorial, and now that that is done, I want to try make a level editor that can save in that format.

The level editor would be quite simple, it would have a blank grid on the left, and another grid on the right with the tileset, you would click a tile, and that would be assigned active, dropping it wherever you click in the level editor.

However, as easy as this sounds, I'm having trouble finding a control for this purpose. I know i could do this in SFML, but I'm looking for a solution that can be done in winforms, if none exists, then I'll do it in SFML.

I considered a panel with a 2d vector or array of image boxes, however; that would get rather inefficient pretty fast. I could set up a viewport so only 20x20 display at any one time, but it still seems slow.

I also considered making a custom control based on DataGridView, but I would have no idea how to do that.

If there is a control for this purpose I'm looking for, can anyone please suggest one? If not, can anyone suggest how I could implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: forget winforms. it's useless. It does not support customization and it's software rendered. Thus slow. You can do this really easily with some 20 lines of XAML in WPF. With a little bit more effort you may also achieve virtualization so that only viewable UI parts are rendered thus gaining even more speed

Comment: @HighCore I ended up just using sfml, I haven't used WPF before though, so i'll look in that.